# What does an exclamation mark mean in the Windows 8.1 Mail App?

Tags: windows-8.1, email

Yesterday, I got an email from my university about a library workshop. I checked it in the Windows 8.1 Mail App. The email came with an exclamation mark in the top right corner.

[image]

What does the exclamation mark mean, and can I remove it? It's the only email in my inbox with that. The email's not flagged, and it's not spam. Everything in the email loaded correctly, so it's not causing problems. I googled "windows 8.1 mail app exclamation mark", but I didn't find anything related. My guess is that it's either a sync problem or somehow a high priority email.

Comment: It means the email was sent as "high-importance".  You cannot remove it because its meta-data of the email itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the email was sent as "High Priority", set by the sender.

In case you want to start setting priorities on your own email, you can use this info from [Mail app for Windows 8.1 - How to change the message priority](http://ccm.net/faq/37106-mail-app-for-windows-8-1-how-to-change-the-message-priority):

> The Mail app of Windows 8.1 allows you to change the priority of your
>   messages. This will allow the e-mail recipients to easily identify
>   important email messages as indicators will be displayed next to them.
>   To change the priority of a message:
>
> • Click on the More button (located below the CC field).
>
> [image]
>
> • Click on the Priority menu and make your selection:
>
> [image]

Comment: Ya, you're right. I can set priority when I send mail in the app. Can't remove it, but I'm supposed not to then haha. Thanks!